# I cannot understand why I cannot login in Spring boot security app?

Tags: spring-boot

Using Intellij.
No visible signs on logging. Just redirecting to login?error url.

On logging I have these log records:

2022-08-27 01:17:39,067 [5934528]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appCachedDictionaryState took 137 ms
2022-08-27 01:18:36,423 [5991884]   INFO - #c.i.i.a.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1
2022-08-27 01:18:40,129 [5995590]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appDontShowAgainFeedbackService took 13 ms, FileTypeManager took 26 ms, FindSettings took 23 ms, GeneralSettings took 15 ms

My github:  https://github.com/anatoliy19/3.1.3.git

Answer (score 0):

The password I tried generated a different string every time so I got wrong match.

The login became successful when I inserted into table the right hash.